# Is there any file to read when on of my datanode was dead

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

**Situation:**
  In my test apache hadoop, I run a MapReduce job.
  If one of my datanode was down (I trun off the machine), and this datanode is   working with my MapReduce job.

**My thinking:**
  I intuitively think, the job will run longer a little bit, besides it will not be failed, because the file block replicates in other nodes.

Some people say I can set the parameters:

**dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.enable = true**
  **dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.best-effort=true**

Therefore my job will skip the dead datanode and look another available one.

**My question is:**
Somebody know **where is the file** I can check it out and see my job's lifecycle?
From a dead datanode to resume another available one?

Firstly I think is editlog, but I can't read it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

please check your datanode and namenode id are same then . if u check datanode file . then u goes to datanode folder  and goes to current directory . then watch file .